# Removed Windows service is still running

Tags: c++, c, service, windows-services, cygwin

I installed a windows service with cygwin cygrunsrv. That service is writing something to a file every 5 seconds. After I tried it, I removed service with "cygrunserv -R service_name". Now, service is removed from services list but it is still running. How can I remove it for real.

Comment: Service is written with C++ and compiled with cygwin gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Windows is solving that issue.

Comment: at first i misread this as 're-installing windows is solving this' :)